# TikZ/pgf: When using the `graphdrawing` library, why do components still overlap even after `component sep` has been defined?

Tags: tikz-pgf

**The source:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\SP#1{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\def\SB#1{\textsubscript{#1}}
\def\SPSB#1#2{\rlap{\textsuperscript{#1}\textsubscript{#2}}}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees, ogdf}
%======================================

\begin{document}

            \tikz 
            \graph [spring layout, node distance = 20mm, nodes = draw, component sep = 5mm, component packing = rectangular]
            {

                RacOn/"\textbf{Rac\SB{on}}";
                kRacOnToOffM/"${k^{{Rac}}_{{on}\rightarrow{off}}}$";
                kRacOffMtoOn/"${k^{{Rac}}_{{on}\leftarrow{off}}}$";

                Rac [draw, circle] // [spring layout, node distance = 10mm, component sep = 5mm, component packing = rectangular]
                {   
                    RacOn ->[very thick, bend right, orient = 90]
                    kRacOffMtoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, blue, orient = 90]
                    RacOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, red, orient = 90] 
                    kRacOnToOffM 
                };

                RhoOn/"\textbf{Rho\SB{on}}";
                kRhoOnToOffM/"${k^{{Rho}}_{{on}\rightarrow{off}}}$";
                kRhoOffMtoOn/"${k^{{Rho}}_{{on}\leftarrow{off}}}$";

                Rho [draw, circle] // [spring layout, node distance = 10mm, component sep = 5mm, component packing = rectangular]
                {   
                    kRhoOffMtoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, blue]
                    RhoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, red] 
                    kRhoOnToOffM 
                };

                chemoattractant/"chemoattractant";
                %chemoattractant -!- Rac;
                %chemoattractant -!- Rho;

                chemorepellant/"chemorepellant";
                %chemorepellant -!- Rac;
                %chemorepellant -!- Rho;

                memProtrusion/"membrane protrusion";
                %memProtrusion -!- Rac;
                %memProtrusion -!- Rho;

                memRetraction/"membrane retraction";
                %memRetraction -!- Rac;
                %memRetraction -!- Rho;

                memTension/"membrane tension";
                %memTension -!- Rac;
                %memTension -!- Rac;

                contact/"intercellular contact";
                %contact -!- Rac;
                %contact -!- Rho;

                chemoattractant ->[very thick] kRacOffMtoOn; 
                chemorepellant ->[very thick] kRhoOffMtoOn;

                RacOn ->[very thick, bend right] memProtrusion ->[very thick] memTension ->[very thick] kRacOnToOffM;

                RhoOn ->[very thick] memRetraction ->[>=|, very thick] memTension;

                contact ->[very thick, bend right] kRhoOffMtoOn;


            };

\end{document}
```

**The output:**

[image]

**The question:**

I turned on border drawing for all of the nodes, as you can see above, and you can see how a lot of them still overlap, even after I have specified a `component sep` key.

My guess as to what is happening is that for some reason, the "text" of each node, isn't taken into account when doing these calculations.

What should I do in order to achieve proper separation?

Comment: Not related to the question, but did you manage to install the `ogdf` library? If so, in which architecture?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am not sure if I truly managed to install it, as I  am unable to use its components. For example, I always get the error that the key `BalloonLayout` is not recognized. It's in my source because I forgot to remove it after attempting to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another suggestion with `layered layout`

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\SP#1{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\def\SB#1{\textsubscript{#1}}
\def\SPSB#1#2{\rlap{\textsuperscript{#1}\textsubscript{#2}}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}

\begin{document}
\tikz\graph [layered layout, nodes=draw]
  {
    RacOn/"\textbf{Rac\SB{on}}";
    kRacOnToOffM/"${k^{{Rac}}_{{on}\rightarrow{off}}}$";
    kRacOffMtoOn/"${k^{{Rac}}_{{on}\leftarrow{off}}}$";
%
    Rac [draw, circle]//[spring layout]
      {
        RacOn ->[very thick, bend right, orient = 90]
        kRacOffMtoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, blue, orient = 90]
        RacOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, red, orient = 90] 
        kRacOnToOffM 
      };
%
    RhoOn/"\textbf{Rho\SB{on}}";
    kRhoOnToOffM/"${k^{{Rho}}_{{on}\rightarrow{off}}}$";
    kRhoOffMtoOn/"${k^{{Rho}}_{{on}\leftarrow{off}}}$";
%
    Rho [draw, circle]//[spring layout]
      {
        kRhoOffMtoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, blue]
        RhoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, red] 
        kRhoOnToOffM 
      };
%
    chemorepellant ->[very thick,bend right=30] kRhoOffMtoOn;
    chemoattractant ->[very thick] kRacOffMtoOn;
    contact ->[very thick, bend right] kRhoOffMtoOn;
    RhoOn ->[very thick,bend right=70] memRetraction/"membrane retraction"
      ->[>=|, very thick, bend right=10] memTension/"membrane tension";
    RacOn ->[very thick, bend right=90] memProtrusion/"membrane protrusion" 
      ->[very thick] memTension ->[very thick,bend right=65] kRacOnToOffM;
  };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Increasing the value for `node distance` works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\SP#1{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\def\SB#1{\textsubscript{#1}}
\def\SPSB#1#2{\rlap{\textsuperscript{#1}\textsubscript{#2}}}

%======================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
%======================================

\begin{document}

            \tikz 
            \graph [spring layout, node distance= 5.5cm, nodes = draw, component sep = 50mm, component packing = rectangular]
            {

                RacOn/"\textbf{Rac\SB{on}}";
                kRacOnToOffM/"${k^{{Rac}}_{{on}\rightarrow{off}}}$";
                kRacOffMtoOn/"${k^{{Rac}}_{{on}\leftarrow{off}}}$";

                Rac [draw, circle] // [spring layout, node distance = 10mm, component sep = 5mm, component packing = rectangular]
                {   
                    RacOn ->[very thick, bend right, orient = 90]
                    kRacOffMtoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, blue, orient = 90]
                    RacOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, red, orient = 90] 
                    kRacOnToOffM 
                };

                RhoOn/"\textbf{Rho\SB{on}}";
                kRhoOnToOffM/"${k^{{Rho}}_{{on}\rightarrow{off}}}$";
                kRhoOffMtoOn/"${k^{{Rho}}_{{on}\leftarrow{off}}}$";

                Rho [draw, circle] // [spring layout, node distance = 10mm, component sep = 5mm, component packing = rectangular]
                {   
                    kRhoOffMtoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, blue]
                    RhoOn ->[decorate, decoration=snake, red] 
                    kRhoOnToOffM 
                };

                chemoattractant/"chemoattractant";
                %chemoattractant -!- Rac;
                %chemoattractant -!- Rho;

                chemorepellant/"chemorepellant";
                %chemorepellant -!- Rac;
                %chemorepellant -!- Rho;

                memProtrusion/"membrane protrusion";
                %memProtrusion -!- Rac;
                %memProtrusion -!- Rho;

                memRetraction/"membrane retraction";
                %memRetraction -!- Rac;
                %memRetraction -!- Rho;

                memTension/"membrane tension";
                %memTension -!- Rac;
                %memTension -!- Rac;

                contact/"intercellular contact";
                %contact -!- Rac;
                %contact -!- Rho;

                chemoattractant ->[very thick] kRacOffMtoOn; 
                chemorepellant ->[very thick] kRhoOffMtoOn;

                RacOn ->[very thick, bend right] memProtrusion ->[very thick] memTension ->[very thick] kRacOnToOffM;

                RhoOn ->[very thick] memRetraction ->[>=|, very thick] memTension;

                contact ->[very thick, bend right] kRhoOffMtoOn;


            };

\end{document}
```

[image]

`node distance` has a peculiar behaviour in the case of the `graphdrawing` library, as described in Section **27.3 Padding and Node Distances** of the PGF manual:

> This is minimum distance that the centers of nodes connected by an
>   edge should have. It will not always be possible to satisfy this
>   desired distance, for instance in case the nodes are too big. In this
>   case, the length is just considered as a lower bound.

So, in case the nodes are too big (as is in your case in relation to the originally specified value) the distance was just taken as lower bound.

`node distance` is a somehow strange beast (at least for me) with the `graphdrawing` library; some layouts, for example, silently ignore the option.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However was something I had already tried, and not considered, because that makes my image far too large for reasonable use in a document to be set on A4 sized paper.